# Azure DevOps YAML: Passing a variable from a variable group to a parameter in a template file throws type error

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-pipelines

I am attempting to read a variable from a Variable Group in my YAML file and passing it on to a template file that consumes that value. The template file defines this parameter as a number and the variable group does indeed store this as a number.

Here I have my pipeline that is invoking the template stage-run-tests with the 4 parameters, 3 of which are read from a variable group.

[image: Pipeline Code]

The template accepts the 4 parameters and have them typed as number

[image: Template Code]

However, when I try running the pipeline, I get an error stating that the parameter was expecting a number and what was passed in was not a number.

[image: Build Failure]

If I remove the strong typing and I simply use the parameters as is, then everything work fine.

[image: Without strong typing]

Can anyone help me with what's happening here? What should I do to ensure that I can have the parameters typed and still have the pipeline pass in the value from the variable group?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the `type: number` to `type: string`, as there is no `number` type in a variable group.

Comment: Is there a way to add validation rules on the same then? The reason I had it as number instead of string was to ensure that we didn't end up passing in incorrect parameter types.

Comment: The pipeline will fail if the parameter is invalid. You can not select variable type in a variable group.

Comment: I think I have my answer :) Thanks Cece